# Prolog equivalent rule but error in one

Tags: prolog, predicate

I am currently practicing Prolog for an exam and when I studied old exams I came across a problem, where one had to define a predicate which returns the length of a list. (Example: `lengthof([a,b,c,d,e,f],Length).` evaluates to `Length=6.`)

My approach was the following:

```
lengthof([],0).
lengthof(List,LengthNew) :- lengthof([_|List],Length),LengthNew is Length-1.
```

But it always threw a stack overflow error. I didn't know what I could have done wrong, so I took a look into the solutions. The solution for this problem is the following:

```
lengthof([],0).
lengthof([_|List],LengthNew) :- lengthof(List,Length),LengthNew is Length+1.
```

I am now wondering why my approach did not work out. What is wrong with this one? Logically and at first look, I think, that both approaches are equivalent.

Comment: In your first attempt, the recursive case keeps *growing* the list, but the base case assumes it's going to *shrink* to `[]`. Thus, your first solution just keeps growing the list, unbounded. `[_|List]` will never become `[]`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) I see, I didn't know that it's handled like that. In words, my idea was: "If you have a list, and remove the first element, then the resulting list will have the length of the first list minus one" So in the end, there would be my fallback of `lengthof([],0)` and I'd get my result

Comment: The statement you made is true: *If you have a list, and remove the first element, then the resulting list will have the length of the first list minus one* but your first solution doesn't match that statement. Your first solution says, *The length of a list `List` is the value `LengthNew` if the length of list `[_|List]` is the value `Length` and `LengthNew` is `Length - 1`*. In other words, *The length of a list is one less than the length of a list that has an additional element*. As you can see, the recursive definition (*a list that has an additional element*) keeps growing the list.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, that explains it really well. Yes my intention was to code exactly that statement, but I confused the left and right side of the `:-`-operator. Can this operator mathematically be seen as implication `=>`? Like: `A :- B` is equivalent to `A => B`? Because I thought it would mean `<=`

Comment: It is an implication of sorts. It says, that the head of the clause is true *if* the complete expression that follows is true. That's how I expressed my second statement in my last comment: *The length of a list `List` is the value `LengthNew` **if** ...*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lengthof([],0).
```

this string means that legth of empty list is zero.

```
lengthof([_|List],LengthNew) :- 
  lengthof(List,Length),LengthNew is Length+1.
```

in the rule you say, that no empty list has to consider as first element (_) and other elements (List). And that length of the all list is length of "List" plus one.

But in this rule:

```
lengthof(List,LengthNew) :- 
  lengthof([_|List],Length),LengthNew is Length-1.
```

you say that length of initial list ("List") is length of more big list minus one.
It is true for any list, but it is no solution of your problem, because your code does not calculate length of initial list - instead of this you inclrease initial list endlessly.

Your first rule that process empty list desribes condition of recursion exit. So your second rule must decrease size of list, but you try increase it, so you receive "stack overflow" error.

Comment: Oh no I see, thank you! I had a wrong interpretation of the syntax. Now it's clear, thank you.